# How to Show time difference or reverse time in android

Tags: java, android

```
class revrsetime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(setLastSeenTime("26/08/2014 14:29:00"));

    }

    public static String setLastSeenTime(String time) {

        long milliseconds = Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis()
                - converTimeStringINToMillis(time));

        String lastSeen = "";

        long seconds = (long) milliseconds / 1000;
        if (seconds < 60)
            lastSeen = String.valueOf(seconds) + "sec ago";
        else if (seconds > 60 && seconds < 3600)
            lastSeen = String.valueOf((int) seconds / 60) + " min ago";
        else if (seconds > 3600 && seconds < 86400)
            lastSeen = String.valueOf((int) seconds / 3600) + " hours ago";
        else if (seconds > 86400 && seconds < 172800)
            lastSeen = " Yesterday";
        else if (seconds > 172800 && seconds < 2592000)
            lastSeen = String.valueOf((int) (seconds / (24 * 3600)))
                    + " days ago";
        else if (seconds > 2592000)
            lastSeen = String.valueOf((int) (seconds / (30 * 24 * 3600)))
                    + " months ago";

        return lastSeen;

    }

    private static long converTimeStringINToMillis(String time) {

        long milliseconds = 0;

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

            // 25/06/2014 8:41:26

            Date date;

            date = sdf.parse(time);
            milliseconds = date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            milliseconds = 0;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return milliseconds;
    }

}
```

This my code for display Lastseendate and time what I am doing this I have getting time from web service and system time make it differences. In some cases I am getting the correct Output but in others I am not.

The output when I set date and time : 26/08/2014 13:29:00 then it shows 3 hours ago when it should show 2 hours ago. When I set 26/08/2014 14:29:00 then it shows 4 hours ago.

I don't know where I'm making the mistake, please help.

Comment: Have you put in breakpoints to see what the number of milliseconds have been to check that it's what you expect?

Comment: yes i Put Brak Point

Comment: u just run this code u also will face same issue

Comment: So it came up with (roughly) the value that you'd expect it to?

Comment: i dont know where is going wrong

Comment: I don't know if it'll help, but I don't think that you need to cast to `int` in your `String.valueOf()` calls

Comment: i got Solution   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); i have to remove this thats it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));   remove this in Code it will Work fine.